# Nodejs & Angularjs, Clean urls

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mod-rewrite

How do I setup node/angular to have the `index.html/app` run at `example.com` rather than `example.com/app/index.html#/home`

I tried putting the `index.html` at the root of the node server but that still leaves the url as `example.com/index.html#/home`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is to enable `html5mode`. It's documentation and considerations can be found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location).

Here's an example taken from [Brian Ford](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express.html):

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives']).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // configure $routeProvider, then...
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
]);
```

The angular-ui framework has [example configuration](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#wiki-how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) for wiring this up to express.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/partials'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendfile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(3006); //the port you want to use
```

In Brian's article, you don't have to manually map the static asset folders because his example delivers the single `index.html`, maps partials to `/partials/:name`, then interacts with `/api/*`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yoeman, or grunt build on your NODEJS server.

You can simple add new file `server.js` into root folder, and if your app folder is inside and your root folder.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/app"));

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
  res.sendFile('/app/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
var port = 1337;
app.listen(port); //the port you want to use
console.log('Server running at localhost:' + port);
```

And make sure you have enabled HTML5 mode inside your AngularJs config

```js
angular.module('yourApp')
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/some', {
        templateUrl: '../templates/some.html'
      })

      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    //enabling HTML5 mode
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
  ]);
```